# IE 9 and below issue when displaying my slide out sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I created a 100% width and height slide out sidebar menu that displays when you click the menu button. Everything works great until it come to ie9 and below. What happens is instead of pressing menu to slide out the menu, the menu is already being displayed covering the whole site.

How can I get this to function correctly in ie9?

Here is my JS and here is the full functionality http://jsfiddle.net/pc89G/8/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $frm = $('#menu').hide();
var $bts = $("#menu-trigger").on('click', function () {
var $this = $(this)
    $bts.filter(".selected").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $this.toggleClass('selected');
if ($this.hasClass('selected') && $frm.is(':visible')) {
    $frm.stop(true, true).slideUp(function () {
    $(this).slideDown()
});
    } else {
    $frm.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    }
});
    $bts.filter('.selected').click();
$("#content, a.gn-icon-menu").click(function () {
    $bts.filter(".selected").removeClass('selected');
    $frm.slideUp();
});
    $bts.filter('.selected').hover();
    $("a.gn-icon-menu").hover(function () {
    $bts.filter(".selected").removeClass('selected');
    $frm.slideUp();
});
 });

 ;( function( window ) {
'use strict';
 function mobilecheck() {
var check = false;
(function(a)     {if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
}
function gnMenu( el, options ) {    
    this.el = el;
    this._init();
}
gnMenu.prototype = {
    _init : function() {
        this.trigger = this.el.querySelector( 'a.gn-icon-menu' );
        this.menu = this.el.querySelector( 'nav.navMenu-wrapper' );
        this.isMenuOpen = false;
        this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        this._initEvents();

        var self = this;
        this.bodyClickFn = function() {
            self._closeMenu();
            this.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
        };
    },
    _initEvents : function() {
        var self = this;

        if( !mobilecheck() ) {
            this.trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) { self._openIconMenu(); } );
            this.trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) { self._closeIconMenu(); } );

            this.menu.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
                self._openMenu(); 
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
            } );
        }
        this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if( self.isMenuOpen ) {
                self._closeMenu();
                document.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
            }
            else {
                self._openMenu();
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn );
            }
        } );
        this.menu.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); } );
    },
    _openIconMenu : function() {
        classie.add( this.menu, 'gn-open-part' );
    },
    _closeIconMenu : function() {
        classie.remove( this.menu, 'gn-open-part' );
    },
    _openMenu : function() {
        if( this.isMenuOpen ) return;
        classie.add( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
        this.isMenuOpen = true;
        classie.add( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
        this._closeIconMenu();
    },
    _closeMenu : function() {
        if( !this.isMenuOpen ) return;
        classie.remove( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
        this.isMenuOpen = false;
        classie.remove( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
        this._closeIconMenu();
    }
}

// add to global namespace
window.gnMenu = gnMenu;

 } )( window );

  new gnMenu( document.getElementById( 'navMenu' ) );   
 ( function( window ) {

      'use strict';
  function classReg( className ) {
        return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
 }

  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
        hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
        return elem.classList.contains( c );
 };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
  elem.classList.add( c );
 };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
        elem.classList.remove( c );
      };
 }
  else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
  return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
 };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
  if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
  elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
 }
 };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
  elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
 };
 }

  function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
   var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
   fn( elem, c );
 }

  var classie = {
   // full names
   hasClass: hasClass,
   addClass: addClass,
   removeClass: removeClass,
   toggleClass: toggleClass,
   // short names
   has: hasClass,
   add: addClass,
   remove: removeClass,
   toggle: toggleClass
 };

 // transport
  if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD
   define( classie );
      } else {
   // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
 }

 })( window );
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: what's the problem exactly? please clearify!

Comment: The problem I am having is in IE9 the menu is not hidden when you first view the site. Instead of being hidden as it is in the  http://jsfiddle.net/pc89G/8/ IE 9 is causing the menu to be active. Causing the menu to cover the whole website and I am unable to close the menu. @AminJafari If you click the red button you will see the menu slide out. In IE 9 the menu is already being displayed. I tried posting an image but I do not have enough points.

Comment: Is it maybe to do with your CSS? Could be a CSS quirk of IE9 is stopping the menu from being hidden (not that anything comes to mind that might cause this).

Comment: checking out your CSS I noticed that you haven't given any CSS to `.navMenu-wrapper`, try styling this div! you made something that could be done so easily so hard :-s

Comment: When I open the F12 dev tools in IE9, I hit a jQuery error pretty much straight away (`SCRIPT5: Access is denied. jquery-1.10.1.js, line 1513 character 2`). As a result, `'$' is undefined` so your other script won't run. I can't see what actually causes the error but I suspect that'll be the key.

Comment: do you have something I can look at to simplify this? @AminJafari

Comment: I though it was the css as well but unable to figure out this. I got this code from a tutorial I found and tweaked it a bit. I did some research and it seems IE 9 does not read addEventListener correctly @Noodlemanny

Comment: I'm working on it, please wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple logic behind it is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bC5zh/

```
$(function(){
    window.status=0;
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        if(window.status==0){
            $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({left:'0px'},500); 
            window.status=1;
        }
        else{
            $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({left:'-100%'},500);
            window.status=0;
        }
    });
})
```

see if it enlightens an idea! ;)

P.S. it works on all versions of browsers [tested]

Comment: would you know how to make the #sliding menu have the ability to scroll once its positioning is set to fixed? When the sliding menu is set to absolute it only fills the screen. When I scroll down the slidingMenu gets cut off. I would like to ability to fill the screen with the slidingMenu and have the ability to only scroll whats in that menu @AminJafari

Comment: just set `position:fixed;` and `overflow-y:scroll;` see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/bC5zh/3/

Comment: I did that, but you will notice that there is a gap between the end of the page and the div. Also you will notice when the div slide out you will see a white bar (scrollbar) attached. Is there away that I can eliminate that ability and have the main scrollbar control that div once it is selected? @AminJafari

Comment: not exactly, but you could hide the main page scrollbar on click and then show it again on hide which looks kinda like you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bC5zh/12/

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again but there seems to be a problem when the new code you sent me. When you hide the main scrollbar it takes to the new div that is bing displayed. But when you close the menu the scrollbar will not allow me to scroll down the whole page. What can be causing this @ArminJafari